# how to make vertically align tabs in android

Tags: android, tabwidget, android-tabs

i worked with tabwidget in android to make it vertically align but couldn't find an effective way to accomplish it

here is what i want to achieve

[image]

Comment: You may need fragment for it...

Comment: @Pragnani please elaborate

Answer (score -1):

You can place a column of buttons which look like tabs and change the content of the ListView on the side